# How to lock on single ConcurrentHashMap object for modification without blocking whole map?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, nonblocking, concurrenthashmap

Is there an easy way to lock on ConcurrentHashMap object during its modification without blocking whole map? As far as I know here is simple way in Java 8 - method **competeIfPresent** , but unfortunately I've got 1.7 java on project.

```
private Map<Long, AtomicInteger> idForCountMap;

public void decrement(Long id) {
    AtomicInteger count = idForCountMap.get(id);
    if (count != null){
    count.decrementAndGet();
    // do some additional operations
    }
}
```

Here is an example. How can I perform decrement opeperation as atomic one WITHOUT blocking whole map?

p.s. suppose it's quite common situation, but I could not find fine explained answer.

Comment: Lock the element

Comment: `decrementAndGet()` *is* already an atomic operation.

Comment: Holger, yes but both operations 
idForCountMap.get(id);
count.decrementAndGet(); they are not atomic

Comment: @JohnKorch, as you have it written is effectively atomic. If you get a non-`null` reference to `count`, it will be valid for the entire life of your `decrement` method. The only "issue" is that another thread could put an `AtomicInteger` into the `ConcurrentHashMap` just after you call `get(id)` but before you check for `null`, but I don't see how that would necessarily be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think  it will workout if you can bring a shared key for the mapped value, and acquire a lock on the key for the complete operation.

```
public void decrement(SharedKey id) {
synchronized(id){
     AtomicInteger count = idForCountMap.get(id);
     if (count != null){
        count.decrementAndGet();
        // do some additional operations
     }
}
}
```